# Swift takeRetainedValue() and takeUnretainedValue() both EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have objc function that return `SecIdentityRef`

```
+ (SecIdentityRef)getSecIdentity {
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert1" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *p12Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath];
NSMutableDictionary * options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[options setObject:@"123456" forKey:(id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];

CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import((CFDataRef) p12Data,
                                         (CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);

if (securityError == noErr && CFArrayGetCount(items) > 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    SecIdentityRef identityApp =
    (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                         kSecImportItemIdentity);
    CFRelease(items);
    return identityApp;
}

CFRelease(items);
return NULL;
}
```

I import class with this function in bridging header, then use it in swift code

```
let test = Certificate.getSecIdentity()
let secIdentity = test.takeUnretainedValue()
```

From `Certificate.getSecIdentity()` returns `Unmanaged<SecIdentityRef>` with correct (?) SecIdentity inside.

[image]

On `test.takeUnretainedValue()` (and `test.takeRetainedValue()`) I receive
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2d13e474f3e0)`

What I do wrong? How can I get SecIdentity?

Comment: You say, with some uncertainty, that `test` has the correct `SecIdentity` inside.   Are you saying that because you viewed the contents of `_value` or is that based on the address the debugger shows in your screenshot?

Comment: Because of address

Comment: In that case, it would be a good idea to put a break point on the Obj-C line where you return it, and look at the actual value.  Maybe put in a printf or NSLog or something.  Basically verify first that the Obj-C code is actually obtaining a proper `SecIdentity`.  Then step out and look at it again on the Swift side before `takeUnretainedValue`.  Ensure that it's the same data at least.   I don't know what's the problem is, but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve an element from (i believe) any core foundation collection, the collection functions follows the [Get-Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1). It means that you don't own the element until you explicitly retain it. Thus in this part of your code:

> ```c
> SecIdentityRef identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);
> CFRelease(items);
> ```

You essentially release both `items` and `identityApp` and return a dangling pointer (a dangling core foundation reference to be precise). Just retain the instance of `SecIdentityRef` before your release the `items` array like that:

```c
CFRetain(identityApp);
CFRelease(items);
return identityApp;
```

---

**P.S.** since your function may return `NULL`, you better make the result `nullable`, especially when working with Swift, so it knows the result is an optional value:

```objc
+ (nullable SecIdentityRef)getSecIdentity
```

**P.P.S.** you also may want to rewrite you code in Swift directly, since [it supports work with `SecCertificate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccertificate)

Comment: Yes, I've actually already rewrote this on swift =) Thanks for answer